# socket programming with getaddrinfo

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I'm using getaddrinfo in my socket programming in linux. I have created a client and a server. Currently the client has a hardcoded static port number. Everything works fine.

But I want the system to dynamically assign a port number to the client whenever it connects to the server. How do I do this using getaddrinfo?
I'm using a TCP socket.

Comment: This does not make sense - the client should be connecting to the server on a specified IP address and port number. The server cannot arbitrarily assign a new port number once the connection is established - unless I have misunderstood what you want here of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `bind` before calling `connect` and the TCP stack will assign the client a "random" source port. If you need to know what port you're connecting from (and you usually don't), you can call `getsockaddr` *after* calling `connect`.

Alternatively, can call `bind` specifying port 0. In that case, again, the stack will assign the client a "random" unused source port to connect from. This option would be preferred if you don't want to special case allowing the implementation to select the port or if you need to specify the local IP address for some reason.